# Apache : How to redirect domain.com:2368 to domain.com/blog

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, redirect, port, ghost-blog

I have standard Apache configuration.
At `domain.com` Apache is serving static html files (No backend technology)

At `domain.com:2368`, there is a Ghost (blogging platform) instance, running NodeJS.

I want to have the following effect:

People should come in at `domain.com/blog` and it should redirect (the content, not the URL) to the Ghost instance at the specific port.

So far, i have managed to make `blog.domain.com` to point at Ghost, but I want `/blog` to work too.

Here is my main VH:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com

    DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/domain.com/
    ServerName domain.com
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /srv/www/htdocs/domain.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the additional VH which redirects the port to blog.domain.com

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName blog.domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2368/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:2368/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `ProxyPass /blog http://127.0.0.1:2368` ... in your domain.com vhost

Comment: Yes but Ghost is looking for resources and not finding them that way :/

Comment: GET http://domain.com/assets/css/screen.css 404 (Not Found) blog:17
GET http://domain.com/shared/vendor/jquery/jquery.js 404 (Not Found) blog:84
GET http://domain.com/assets/js/index.js 404 (Not Found) blog:87

Comment: It seems that Ghost is not supporting subdirectories right now - https://ghost.org/forum/installation/341-how-do-i-run-ghost-on-a-subdirectory/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ghost added support for this in 0.4 - https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Release-Notes:-0.4.0